# Angular Material 2 - How to fix broken icons alignment inside buttons?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to make some buttons with `angular2-material`. Here is the code:

```
<md-card>
<button md-icon-button>
  <md-icon class="md-24">favorite</md-icon>
</button>
<button md-fab>
  <md-icon class="md-24">add</md-icon>
</button>
<button md-mini-fab>
  <md-icon class="md-24">add</md-icon>
</button>
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

It should work correctly without any additional manipulations but it doesn't (as you can see, icons are placed at the bottom of buttons). Any ideas on what's wrong with that? I don't have any css styles that affect these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using different **`md-fab`** with each icons, if you want to make it uniform set md-fab to all the three

```
<md-card md-fab> 
<button md-icon-button>
  <md-icon class="md-24">favorite</md-icon>
</button>
<button md-fab>
  <md-icon class="md-24">add</md-icon>
</button>
<button md-fab>
  <md-icon class="md-24">add</md-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: you need to use row and divide into three columns using flex and put the buttons, learn about material layout first. but this definitely answer your question